# HTTP Error when trying to edit Joomla on localhost

Tags: localhost

I made a backup of my live Joomla 3.7.5 site using Akeeba and used kickstart to upload the backup to MAMP on Windows. The front-side of the site on localhost displays correctly and I am able to log in to the admin side. But, when I try to edit an article, or initiate updates to Joomla, extensions, etc I get:

> HTTP Error 500

I am new to Joomla so any help you can provide would be appreciated. Let me know what additional info you may need.

I tried renaming the .htaccess file to .htaccess.old and a new htaccess file was created, with no effect.

**Expected Result**: edit an article or update Joomla/extensions

**Actual Result**: Click on Edit or Update and receive HTTP Error 500

Comment: In your administrator section select the Global Configuration and under the Server tab set Error Reporting level to Maximum or Development and it should provide you with an error message instead of the 500

Comment: What PHP version do you use on your local MAMP server? What PHP version did you use on the server? Are you using any 3rd party extensions? Are they compatible with your local PHP version? Could you switch OFF Joomla's SEF completely to test if it works without SEF?